# How to popup menu using SendMessage?

Tags: windows, winapi, message

I have pop-up menu, for example:

- "..."
- "PopUp-menu"

  - "Menuitem1"
  - "Menuitem2"
- "..."

How to popup "PopUp-menu" using SendMessage function? Is it possible? course Menuitem has ID, and POPUP menu - has not

Answer (score 1):

the "ID" of a popup menu is its handle, but it's not clear what you mean by "popup the menu using `SendMessage`".  What you would normally do is to get the handle of the "PopUp-Menu" and then pass that to [TrackPopupMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648002(VS.85).aspx) rather than `SendMessage`.

Comment: Maybe I was wrong using PopUp term. I mean, that I have menu with subitems, I can open this menu and show its subitems using mouse cursor, but I want to open this menu and show subitems using SendCommand. Is it possible?

Comment: Not reliably, the first time the user moves the mouse the menu will respond to the mouse rather than to your messages.  Also, once you show a menu, you don't really have a place to hang the code to do the SendMessage anyway. your code doesn't get control back until the menu is dismissed.